# All libraries are showing error after updating SDK version to 24.3 in Android

Tags: android, svn, google-play-services, subclipse, android-sdk-tools

All libraries ware fine before updating the sdk. Just now I update the sdk through sdk manager and everything is out of control now. All libraries are showing only one cross mark on its folder and no error inside. I have taken some images to show something here.

v7 lib:

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't found any issue inside the library.

google-play-service-lib:
[image: google-play-service-lib]

same issue.

Fortunately I have found some errors in Error Log, but its not sufficient for me to resolve.
[image]

Android SDK Manager:

[image]

The main issue is it deleted all R.Java classes from all projects in which these libraries are involved.

Can anyone knows how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you update the libraries too??

Comment: @PrerakSola yes, I have updated all including extras.

Comment: I was about to update mine too, but saw your question. Now even I am afraid..!! Did you try cleaning and building the project? Also, you can try by restarting the eclipse

Comment: Yes. I did all as you suggested, but no changes. I did not face this issue before. Don't know Its for sdk tools or subeclipse.

Comment: I can see on the web, the issues related to this version of sdk. But they are for xamarin.

Comment: Don't create invalid tags, please. There is no such thing as "subeclipse". It's called "subclipse".

Comment: ohh sorry for the mistake. I changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by deleting two apis i.e API 22(Android M) and Tools. Don't know why the issue is coming after installing these APIs. After all I'm able to get  **R.java classes** and recompile the apps.  I have attached a image of both packages after deleting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me also .. somehow the files mainly (**R.java**) got corrupted after latest sdk update, that's why you can observe support library name also changed from **appcompat_v7** to **android-support-v7-appcompat**.

**Solution** that worked for me is **remove** all the libraries from workspace which have error & **re-import** them to my workspace.

**For example** -  for importing support library **appcompat_v7** , re-import it from your sdk location:

> (\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat)

Likewise do **re-import** for other corrupted libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Amrit. But I already re importing  all libraries 2/3 times already. But no change..Ok let me try it again.

Comment: Alright let me check in another system, will let you know status after updating sdk.

Comment: Yes update done and no problem here in my side, may be you can delete that latest sdk tools package & install it once again. Not sure though..!!